# jBBCode - BBcode to html

Tags: php, bbcode

#### What I'm trying to do

I'm trying to use [jBBCode](http://jbbcode.com/) to parse and de-parse bbcode into and from html.

#### The problem

When trying to get the html and turn that back in to bbcode, it just displays html.
Here is the code I'm using to try and switch html back into bbcode.

```
$parser = new JBBCode\Parser();
$parser->loadDefaultCodes();
         
$parser->parse($MYHTMLSTRING);
         
echo $parser->getAsBBCode();
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? I'm sure it's something very simple that I haven't figured out. Any help is appreciated! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`$parser->parse()` takes as input BBCode, not HTML.**

After studying the documentation, it is my understanding that this is a one-way parser:

BBCode -> HTML

I believe the design is for you to store the BBCode in your database, and then when it is time to render HTML to visitors, you parse the BBCode at that time.

This way, you are always storing the raw, editable BBCode in the database.

This is a pretty common design-pattern. For example, for applications that use the Markdown Language (instead of BBCode), they typically store raw markdown in the database and only render it to HTML at page-load time.

**In Summary:**

1. Store Raw BBCode/Text in your database
2. when you render a page to a visitor, you do your conversion at that time (to HTML).

   - $parser->parse($MyBBCode); echo $parser->getAsHTML();
3. If the user edits the BBCode, save that straight back to DB as BB Code

[Documentation Reference](http://jbbcode.com/docs#DocumentElement)

Comment: This method of doing it makes more sense. Thanks :D